# MVC3 Client side Validation is not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, client-side-validation

I have a page in my application in which I have applied MVC Client side validation using `validate.min.js` and `validate.unobtrusive.min.js` but its not working. Validation is working fine on server side, but not on client side. I think the js I used for menu might creating the problem. But I am not able to understand how to solve it, as the menu I used I require that menu effects.

Anyone if have any idea please share.

code of View page:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<ApricaCRMEvent.Models.User_Detail>" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">
    RegisterUser1
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

<h2>RegisterUser1</h2>

<script src="<%: Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js") %>" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="<%: Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js") %>" type="text/javascript"></script>

<% using (Html.BeginForm()) { %>
    <%: Html.ValidationSummary(true) %>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>User_Detail</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.Username) %>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <%: Html.EditorFor(model => model.Username) %>
            <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Username) %>
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.Password) %>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <%: Html.EditorFor(model => model.Password) %>
            <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Password) %>
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.Email_Add) %>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <%: Html.EditorFor(model => model.Email_Add) %>
            <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email_Add) %>
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.Alt_Email_Add) %>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <%: Html.EditorFor(model => model.Alt_Email_Add) %>
            <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Alt_Email_Add) %>
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.ConfirmPassword) %>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <%: Html.EditorFor(model => model.ConfirmPassword) %>
            <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ConfirmPassword) %>
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
<% } %>

<div>
    <%: Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index") %>
</div>

</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
```

It generates html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head id="Head1"><title>

    RegisterUser1

</title><link href="../Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/modernizr-1.7.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <!-- for Menu (Imp: jquery.js and menu.js must be included at last in links for menu effects to work.)-->
    <link href="../Content/menu.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="../../Scripts/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../../Scripts/menu.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!--- for menu end -->

</head>
<body>
    <div class="page">
        <header>

            <table id="header">

                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div id="aprica_logo">

                            <img src="../../Content/images/Apricalogo.png" alt="Aprica" style="width: 134px;
                                height: 100px;" />
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div align="center" id="title">
                            <h1>
                                Aprica</h1>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div id="logindisplay">

        Welcome <strong>admin</strong>
        [ <a href="/CRMLogin/LogOff">Log Out</a> ]

                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <div id="menu">
                <ul class="menu">
                    <li><a href="#" class="parent"><span>My Account</span></a>
                        <div>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#"><span>Change Password</span></a></li>
                                <li><a href="#"><span>Message Passing</span></a></li>
                                <li><a href="#"><span>Edit Profile</span></a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="/CRMDashboard/Dashboard">
                            <span>Dashboard</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="/CRM/Index" class="parent"><span>CRM Request</span></a>
                        <div>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="/CRM/AddNewCRM"><span>Add New CRM Request</span></a></li>
                                <li><a href="/CRM/ViewNewlyArrivedCRMRequest"><span>CRM Request List</span></a></li>
                                <li><a href="/CRM/NewOldDoctor"><span>CRM Doctors List</span></a></li>
                                <li><a href="/CRM/AddCRMDoctorBudget"><span>Add New CRM Doctor</span></a></li>
                                <li><a href="/CRM/UpdateCRMDoctorBudgetMain"><span>Edit CRM Doctor</span></a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="parent"><span>Reports</span></a>
                        <div>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#" class="parent"><span>Chart Reports</span></a>
                                    <div>
                                        <ul>
                                            <li><a href="/ChartReport/Index"><span>CRM Request Reports</span></a>
                                            </li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="/Report/CRMStatus"><span>CRM Request Status</span></a></li>
                                <li><a href="/Report/DoctorReport"><span>Doctor wise</span></a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="parent"><span>Search</span></a>
                        <div>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="/Search/CRMIdIndex"><span>CRM Request Id Wise</span></a></li>
                                <li><a href="/Search/MDLNoIndex"><span>MDLNo Wise</span></a></li>
                                <li><a href="/Search/TerritoryIndex"><span>Territory Wise</span></a></li>
                                <li><a href="/Search/RequesterIndex"><span>TBM Wise</span></a></li>
                                <li><a href="/Search/PriorityIndex"><span>Priority Wise</span></a></li>
                                <li><a href="/Search/CRMStateIndex"><span>CRM State Wise</span></a></li>
                                <li><a href="/Search/ServiceStateIndex"><span>Service State Wise</span></a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="/FilterCRMRequest/Index"><span>Filter CRM Requests</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><span>Settings</span></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </header>
        <section id="main">


<h2>RegisterUser1</h2>

<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<form action="/CRMLogin/RegisterUser1" method="post">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>User_Detail</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            <label for="Username">Username</label>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <input class="text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Username field is required." id="Username" name="Username" type="text" value="" />
            <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Username" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            <label for="Password">Password</label>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <input class="text-box single-line password" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Password field is required." id="Password" name="Password" type="password" value="" />
            <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Password" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            <label for="Email_Add">Email address</label>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <input class="text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Email address field is required." id="Email_Add" name="Email_Add" type="text" value="" />
            <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Email_Add" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            <label for="Alt_Email_Add">Alternate Email address</label>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <input class="text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Alternate Email address field is required." id="Alt_Email_Add" name="Alt_Email_Add" type="text" value="" />
            <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Alt_Email_Add" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            <label for="ConfirmPassword">Confirm password</label>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <input class="text-box single-line password" data-val="true" data-val-equalto="The password and confirmation password do not match." data-val-equalto-other="*.Password" id="ConfirmPassword" name="ConfirmPassword" type="password" value="" />
            <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="ConfirmPassword" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
</form>    

            <footer>
                <hr />
                <p>
                    Copyright (c) 2012</p>
                <hr />

            </footer>
        </section>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: check in web.config ClientValidationEnabled is set to true.

Comment: it is set true... I checked it

Comment: open up the console on the browser that your using (hit F12) see if there is any client side exceptions, because the first thing i saw u referenced jQuery two times

Comment: I removed one jquery link. but also its not working.

Answer (score 0):

Something of similar nature happened to me and I was able to fix it by reordering scripts. You may try this if all other options runs out.

The order is

```
Jquery-yourversion.js
MicrosoftAjax.js
MicrosoftMvcAjax.js
MicrosoftMvcValidation.js
YourOtherScripts.js
```

I got this tip from another web post, but could not find it now to include it a reference. If this works, credit goes to the author of that post.

Hope this helps you

Comment: Sorry... it doesn't helped. Here the jquey file I used for menu is creating problem for me. and I cant change the menu as my senoir likes it alot...

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem of client side validation not working. I brought up the JavaScript console in Chrome and saw I was receiving an error stating "JQuery was not defined.".

Turns out I had some code in my View that was causing problems with jQuery not loading.

Recommendation to others who come across this, check your JS console in your browser to ensure you are not getting a JQuery error.